# angularjs - remove option from input select

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, forms

Can't figure this out for the life of me.  Using AngularJS.

I have a dropdown Select field with several options.  It is a part of a form that may be completed multiple times (ie "add another" type form).  Now, one of the options may only be used once.  How can I remove this option from all other select fields after it has been used?

What I'm working with:

**html**

```
<select ng-model="item.itemtype">
    <option ng-repeat="i in itemtype" value="{{i}}" ng-init="item.itemtype = itemtype[0]">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```

**angularjs**

```
  $scope.Items = [
    { 'itemtype': '', 'desc': '', 'color': '' }
  ];

  $scope.itemtype = [
    'shirt',
    'pants',
    'hats',
    'shoes',
    'special'];
```

What I've tried (and really doesn't work)

```
  $scope.specialremove = function() {
    var exist = Items.indexOf("special")
    if (exist !== 0) {
      return '';
    }
    else {
      return 'special';
    }
  }
```

I'm hoping I don't have to turn to any other framework to solve this.  Feel free to point out any other problems/errors/inefficiencies in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that can help is using [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):

`ng-options="type for type in itemType"`.

It would be better to have objects with `label` and `value` properties, in order to write it as

`ng-options="type.value as type.label for type in itemType"`

and separate the displayed label from the actual value of the selection.

In your controller you should have something like:

```
  $scope.itemType= [
      ...
  ];
  $scope.selectedItem= $scope.itemType[0];
```

So that you can write the select as:

`<select ng-Model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in itemType"></select>`

To remove a selected item you can `watch` the value of `selectedItem` in the controller: when it matches the value you want, remove it from the array and update `selectedItem` accordingly.

Here is a basic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/kN9ku/5/). I simply remove the third option after selecting it, and reset the selected item to the first.

Comment: Not quite there.  I had started off using ng-options but changed to current after following another S/O rabbithole.  -- SO, this worked fine for the select field itself, but I couldn't get the placeholder option (orig solved using ng-init) to appear nor could I replicate the $watch pop

Comment: What about using `itemType.pop()` with your approach?

Comment: I'll try that.  Angular is pretty new to me, not 100% with the underlying logic - but I'll give it a go and see what happens

Comment: The idea is that you only manipulate the underlying model. Your model in this case is the array of itemTypes, so if you want to remove one you should simply manipulate that. Anyway, if you decide to go with the classical `ngOptions` approach I updated the fiddle to correct a small mistake that prevented the initial selection.

Comment: Hmmm let me see if that correction works for me.  Trying the .pop() with my original method didn't work.  Wondering... should it be .pop or .splice?

Comment: I used pop just to quickly remove the last element, but you can remove the element in the way that fits you best :) I will now try to update the fiddle with your approach as well, let's see if it works.

Comment: I updated the fiddle. Now it does the same thing for your code as well. However, I find that the `ngOptions` approach is cleaner and easier to understand. [Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/kN9ku/5/)